# vim search - setting different colors for text under cursor

Tags: vim, search, colors

Suppose vim search finds 5 matches in my file. I see all 5 of these matches highlighted in yellow. I cycle between these by pressing `n`. But, as my cursor moves from one match to the next, the highlights all remain the same color. This makes it difficult to see what match my cursor is on. Is there a way to tell vim to highlight all matches with one color, and if visiting a match using `n`, then color the currently visiting match differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in option that allows to highlight the current in a different way. While creating the search, you have the `'incsearch'` option, but that's it.

You could use another highlighting on top of the search highlighting, e.g. with `:match`; the special `\%#` regular expression atom restricts the match to the current cursor position:

```
:execute 'match IncSearch /\%#' . @/ . '/'
```

The problem with this is that the highlighting needs to be adapted whenever the current search pattern (`@/`) changes (oh, and it doesn't handle search offsets like `/foo/e-1`). So, you'd need to overwrite all search-related commands (`/`, `*`, etc.) to hook the `:match` command into them. I would not recommend this.